# How to compare 2 API arrays field and print one of the api field using angular rxjs

Tags: angular, api

1st api contains 2 arrays with fields
premiumFrequency
-code
-label

policyStatus
-code
-label

2nd api also contains 2 fields

-policyFrequency
-status

1. if (policyFrequency == premiumFrequency.code) => print: premiumFrequency.label
2. if(status ==policyStatus.code) => print: policyStatus.label

I have attached both api in result using forJoin.
Can access 1st api as result.polices
And 2nd api as result.policiesStatus

How can i compare and display labels in template file?

● JSON data
1st api:
"data": {
"resultMap":
"premiumFrequency": [
{
"id": "YEARLY",
"code": "YEARLY",
"label": "Yearly"
},
{
"id":"NOT_AVAILABLE",
"code":"NOT_AVAILABLE",
"label": "Not available"
},
{
"id": "PREMIUM",
"code": "PREMIUM",
"label": "Premium"
},
],
"policyStatus": [
{
"id": "PROPOSAL",
"code": "PROPOSAL",
"label": "Proposal"
},
{
"id": "IN_SUSPENSE",
"code": "IN_SUSPENSE",
"label": "In suspense"
}
]

2nd api:
"resultList":[
{
"policyFrequency":"MONTHLY",
"status": "IN_FORCE"
},
]

Comment: Can you post the two responses from the API in proper JSON format?

Comment: I have added JSON format for both api.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to approach this. Since you are receiving a response back from two separate api calls, and have decided to use a forkJoin to combine them, we can create two empty arrays at the start of the class. In the subscription of the forkJoined observables, we use the find/some method on arrays as such:

```
apiOne.find(value => apiTwo.some(res => res.policyFrequency === value.code)));
```

We do the same thing on the other response, instead looking where:

```
apiOne.find(value => apiTwo.some(res => res.status === value.code)));
```

None of your API responses have matches however, so I created  a stackblitz project and changed some values so you can see how this works.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hfuu6w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Hey Garrett could you please help me out on this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71868117/angular-store-array-data-in-variable